# Browserlink for Azure Service Fabric .NET Core App

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-service-fabric, browser-link

I'm finding the iterative development cycle quite slow on service fabric as opposed to a standalone .NET Core web application. It does not look like browser link works, hell even refreshing the page doesn't update HTML. From what I can see, you need to restart the whole fabric to update HTML changes.

There has to be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this feature in the pipeline. Will be a few months out, but is coming.

To enable quick iterations on static files and other files that do not need build time compilation, the current hack is to start debugging your app or deploy it to the cluster so it's running. Find the files in the cluster node directory (Typically C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\....) edit them there and refresh your browser. Remember to copy changes over to your source before stopping debugging or removing the app, as this will delete those files.
Make sure to set you local cluster in one-node mode, to ensure you only have the files being served from one directory.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: The feature was released in the 5.5 release (1.5 tooling).  It's called Refresh Application mode and is a property on the Service Fabric application project in Visual Studio.